# Files suddenly disappeared

Tags: hard-drive

I have a weird problem with my computer. It is a desktop running Ubuntu 18.04. Sunday evening I left the computer on, with youtube-dl running, downloading some videos to my home folder, which is located on the same SSD of the system.

In the morning, the files contained in several folders in my data hard disk (which is different from the system disk) had disappeared. Only the files, not the folders.

My hard disk is synced with a self-hosted Nextcloud instance, and the missing files are still on Nextcloud (and also on my backup on Crashplan, so no problems with respect to this). My laptop also syncs with Nextcloud, but I have not turned it on since a few days. So, I don't think it is a synchronization problem. 
It seems that the folders have been erased between 6.30 and 6.50 in the morning.

I have checked the syslog and it seems that more or less at 6.30,  a couple of applications have started complaining that the disk was full. In fact, my system SSD was nearly full (due to the videos downloaded during the night).

Anybody has an idea of what could have happened?

Thanks in advance,

GP

Comment: There are many bugs of this type on nextcloud.